# application crashing on ipod touch but not on iphone emulator

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch

I followed the apple tutorial ["Your First iOS Application"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html) step by step and it works perfectly on the iPhone emulator.

But when I attempt to deploy it on an ipod touch, the application crashes.

here is the problematic method :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    MyViewController *acontroller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self setMyViewController:acontroller];

    [[self window] setRootViewController:[self myViewController]];    // crash here

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [acontroller release];

    return YES;
}
```

And here is the error message :

```
011-04-13 18:07:53.730 ios_HelloWorld[865:207] *** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x119520
2011-04-13 18:07:53.754 ios_HelloWorld[865:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x119520'
2011-04-13 18:07:53.770 ios_HelloWorld[865:207] Stack: (
    843631901,
    849079828,
    843635709,
    843131673,
    843094080,
    11801,
    857435720,
    857434728,
    857767424,
    857765436,
    857763988,
    875472868,
    843380011,
    843377695,
    857431048,
    857424432,
    11553,
    11476
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Consider that I have followed the tutorial step by step (and re-did it by my own) and it always crashes at this spot.

Any idea?

thanks

KiTe

Comment: What iOS is running on your device?

Comment: the emulator --> 4.3
iPod touch --> 3.1.3
I configured the build setting to take account of that (base SDK iOS 4.3, iOS deployment target iOS 3.1.3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[self.window.rootViewController vs window addSubview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248460/self-window-rootviewcontroller-vs-window-addsubview)

Comment: yep, that was the point. didn't notice rootViewController was from 4.0

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the documentation, the desired property is not available on that iOS Version. You will have to update or build in some conditional workaround.

> rootViewController The root view
>   controller for the window.
>
> @property(nonatomic,retain)
>   UIViewController *rootViewController
>   Discussion The root view controller
>   provides the content view of the
>   window. Assigning a view controller to
>   this property (either programmatically
>   or using Interface Builder) installs
>   the view controller’s view as the
>   content view of the window. If the
>   window has an existing view hierarchy,
>   the old views are removed before the
>   new ones are installed.
>
> The default value of this property is
>   nil.
>
> **Availability Available in iOS 4.0 and
>   later.**

Answer (score 1):

The setRootViewController method is only available in iOS 4.0 and above.