# TabbarController crashes in 3.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitabbarcontroller, crash

i am using `TabBarController` , it is working fine in my ipod.

but my application is crashing it 3.0 . any help please?

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController; //crashing here
```

and log shows

```
-[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x127c80
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -    
[UIWindow setRootViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x127c80'
```

Comment: According to the exception, the value you want to set as rootview controller to window is not initialized or NULL.

Comment: ya but it is working well in my ipod , crashing only in 3.0.

Comment: Implement NSZombieEnabled = YES and it will show you the exact crash reason.

Comment: same thing  crashing in self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248460/self-window-rootviewcontroller-vs-window-addsubview) may show you the right direction. Let me know if the problem still continues.

Due to executing on different versions of iOS, that method may have deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The crash is because you're calling a method that doesn't exist, not because your variables are not initialized.

`-setRootViewController` doesn't exist prior to iOS 4.0.  Use

```
[self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
```

instead.

Or, update your target platfor to 4.0.2 or later.  It's probably less than 5% of users that aren't using iOS 4 at this point.