# SubView did not load in the first launching of my application

Tags: iphone, xcode4, subview, mainwindow

I'm new to iPhone development. I tried to build a simple application with a window and a navigation controller as a sub-view of this window. The problem is this: the sub view did not load when I launch the application. I just have a windows with black screen. To load the view controller, I have to quit the application and launch it a second time, then I have my sub view with the navigation controller. I added a button directly in the window to make sure that the black screen is not a problem, but I saw the button at startup.

This is the code I have in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];
    [self.window addSubview:_navigationController.view]; 
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];    
    return YES;
}
```

Do you have any solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have your view hierarchy setup.  The window's rootViewController will be the UINavigationController.  The UINavigationController controls a hierarchy of viewControllers, so when you instantiate it, you need to assign a rootViewController.  Often times this is a subclass of a UITableView.

Because you are alloc/initing the window, I'm assuming that you do not have a XIB/NIB with the UINavigationController and an associated rootViewController like a UITableViewController.  Also, rather than adding the view of your navigation controller, you need to assign the rootViewController, to the window. Since iOS4 this is the preferred way of doing things.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248460/self-window-rootviewcontroller-vs-window-addsubview) as well.  Try this code:

```
YourViewController *yourViewController = /* code for alloc/initing your viewController */
_navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:yourViewController ]
self.window.rootViewController=_navigationController; /* instead of using [self.window addSubview: _navigationController.view] */
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

If you are using a XIB/NIB, then you need to make sure the _navigationController is wired up to the XIB file and has a subclass of a viewController wired up as it's rootViewController.

Good Luck

Comment: Thank you. But it's still the same problem.

Comment: Did u instantiate a UINavigationController?

Comment: Where ? And how am I supposed to do that ?
Thank you.

Comment: Well, in your current code, you are assigning the view of _navigationController as a subview of the window.  Where are you instantiating the _navigationController.  Since you are alloc/initing the window, it appears that you are not using a NIB/XIB, so it could be that your _navigationController is nil.  If you are not using a XIB/NIB, then you need to alloc/init a UINavigationController.